# Connecting Arduino to Python via Bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth, serial-port, arduino

I'm creating a project where I'm attempting to send analog data recorded from an FSR to a computer to generate a real-time graph. I understand the basics of Arduino, Python, Bluetooth, and serial communication, but I want to establish the connection as easily as possible, which means that I don't want to select the serial port via the Arduino IDE.

Is it possible to establish the serial port outside of the IDE? I would like for a serial communication to be established after simply pairing the Bluetooth dongle to the Bluetooth shield.

I am using an Arduino Uno with the Bluefruit EZ-Link Shield:
http://www.adafruit.com/product/1628

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

we've written two tutorials some time ago that will surely help you:

- [How to Configure your Bluetooth Module for the Communication between Scratch and Arduino](http://www.computacaonaescola.ufsc.br/?page_id=43&lang=en)
- [Mobile Robotics with Scratch: Preparing your Linux PC, Arduino and Scratch to communicate wireless via Bluetooth](http://www.computacaonaescola.ufsc.br/?page_id=69&lang=en)

The communication server we use is in Python, so I think it will apply to your problem.

Tip: The bluetooth serial device (/dev/rfcomm0 or /dev/rfcomm1) will appear only **after** you've chosen to connect to the arduino as a **Dev-B** (see the tutorial) using the blueman-manager.

Tip 2: Do not use the **serial.tools.list_ports.comports()** function from serial.tools. It does not detect **rf** devices (it's a problem with the basenames it uses to collect the devices: rf* is not in the list someone imagined, but you won't be debugging standard python libraries). If you want to automatically look if the correct device was created, use the following code:

```
import glob
rfports = list(glob.glob("/dev/rfcomm*"))
```

**Important:** Remember the following:

- You can connect the Bluetooth module directly to the Arduino connecting the RXD/TXD ports of the Bluetooth to the TX/RX ports (RXD<->TX & TXD<->RX !) of the Arduino or
- you can connect the Bluetooth module to any digital ports of the Arduino using the SoftwareSerial lib.

**IF** you use the first option, it is important that the Arduino **is not** connected to the computer via USB, because the USB connection uses the same RX/TX ports of the Arduino and the Bluetooth communication won't work.  Power the Arduino using batteries or a cellphone charger.